# calling reactive function with data to render UI

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have the following data set. I want to select car brand and it should automatically update the corresponding models for that brand in the next selection
say for example the dataset is as follows

```
dataset.csv  KIA         Ford
            Sportage   Mustang
            sorento      Explorer
```

Code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {   
    abc<-reactive({
        abc <- fread("dataset.csv")
    })
    output$choose_brand<-renderUI({
        selectInput("brand","brand",names(abc()))
    })
    output$choose_model<-renderUI({
        # the error is here.how can I call dataset 
        # abc and select a column from that dataset
        selectInput("model","model",a()$input$brand)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
selectInput("model","model",abc()[input$brand])
```

You can't put variables on the right of `$`, use `[]` instead.